# Nutch 1.12, why are the fetched data garbled text?

Tags: java, macos, apache, nutch

**UPDATE: SOLVED**

Turns out that I was being an idiot.
The files Nutch created are Hadoop sequence files, they need to be read and written using class SequenceFile.

---

I built Nutch 1.x following [this guide](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse#Running_Nutch_in_Eclipse), I think it's 1.12.

I'm on OS X, and doing this with JDK 1.8.0_92 (the latest one).

I have added the following codes in nutch-site.xml, and changed the nutch-default.xml with them too.

```
<property>
    <name>parser.character.encoding.default</name>
    <value>utf-8</value>
</property>
```

I even hardcoded ./src/plugin/parse-html/src/java/org/apache/nutch/parse/html/HtmlParser.java

```
private final String defaultCharEncoding="UTF-8";
this.defaultCharEncoding = getConf().get(
    "parser.character.encoding.default", "UTF-8");
```

And then I ran the following main classes (I was crawling reddit):

```
org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector
org.apache.nutch.crawl.Generator
org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher
org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseSegment
```

which completed well.

But the fetched data files are all in garbled text, like this:

£aπHÉ"EJöIIµí╦÷t║½ü&║╗└>Bûb┐∞≈²ôg3½·Ü(╖

I've been stuck for hours by now, please help.

Comment: Can you share the exact URL that caused the issue?

Comment: @JorgeLuis It's not about any specific URL, anything I crawled was in garbled text.